# How can I minimize the height of my columns using jQuery inside media query?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on minimizing the heights of multiple columns throughout the [tti-fl.com](http://www.tti-fl.com/) website. These columns have a locked height in the media query that when I change the height that they lose mobile responsiveness.

The columns have such excess white space in their layout that I want to fix that to either `10px` for things like desktops and laptops (`@media 992px` and `@media 1022 px` respectively) and then `300px` for tablets and smartphones (`@media 481px` and `@media 768px` respectively).

I heard about using jQuery and I was wondering how I could use this coding language to make the columns smaller than bigger. The elements I'm trying to edit include:

```
.categories-wrapper .content-block /*for 768px and up to 992px*/{
    text-align: center;
}
.home .categories-wrapper .content-block {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The columns start with `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">`. There are other columns, but they are plugins that I do not know how to edit.

Comment: Are you attempting to make the columns all the same height, but smaller? Or do you want them each to be different heights depending on how much text you have inside of them? On `.categories-wrapper .contentblock` add `min-height:auto; height:auto;` to the css.

Comment: I'm looking to make them smaller, but have the same height. I'll see what that does first. Am I also supposed to add this to the other one as well?

Comment: Adding it to `.home` will likely only effect categories on the home page. Also, the solution above will make them different heights depending on the content inside. If you don't want that, it's not the correct solution.

Comment: The home catgeories css is for the static front page. The catgeories-wrapper does not continue to the front page. Hence, why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you wish to control the heights of divs at certain breakpoints. This can be done easily using [match media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 991px)").matches) {
    //jquery selector
    $('.categories-wrapper .content-block').css('height', 50 + 'px');
}
```

Or whatever other options you want. I would put this in a resize function so the browser reacts accordingly when shrunk down or expanded. Otherwise you will have a fixed height per browser load.

Of course, the solution to your problem might be much easier. Could you simply remove the fixed height of the divs? Maybe look into flexbox if you need the divs to be the same height with different amounts of content in them?

Comment: How could I use flexbox that it doesn't affect the CSS?

Comment: @HeatherWilkins Is there a reason you don't want to effect the CSS? It would be much easier than using JS. I only included the match media thing to show you it is possible. It might be helpful to have a bit more info about the project, maybe the specific page or html that is causing the problem.

Comment: It is the static front page that we tried directly changing the heights of the columns to 10px for large computers and desktops. But the smartphones would shrink enormously. Same with the 300px on the tablets. But how can I locate fixed div heights in the WordPress template?

Comment: how would I use this on the HTML side? Would it go between row or content-block?

Comment: Ah I see. Wordpress themes can be tricky to overwrite/navigate if you didn't build them. I see that the style sheet is located here:

http://www.tti-fl.com/wp-content/themes/thermal-tech/style.css

So either in the dashboard editor or through FTP you might be able to access that file and make changes.

Also, flexbox would be a great solution for this problem. It is my go to when I want the columns to be the same height of the one with the largest content, which is what I think you are going for here. You could achieve the effect by writing just a few simple css rules. No extra html

Comment: Thank you. I'll try flex box, but would I need to erase the heights in the media queries for the multiple devices?

Comment: I just added display:flex and deleted the heights from the queries. But I messed up the smartphone screens somehow. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing they all display in a row? If so, then you can add a new rule at any media query size you want. On the parent div with the rule that says "display: flex" simply add "flex-direction: column". This will display the divs in a stack instea of a row. If that is still giving you trouble you can remove the flex altogether and set the parent to "display: block" like normal and the bootstrap styles should take over and stack again. Definitely read up on the doc link I sent, it's very handy